# What does it mean when someone says: "King me"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

When two children are playing chess or something like that, what does it mean when one kid says: "King me"?

Comment: Check out [the rules of checkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts).

Comment: Yes, checkers/draughts (as seen in the answers) but not chess.  In chess you may hear "queen me", though.

Answer (score 1):

It is a phrase drawn from the verb form of **king** that originated in checkers and draughts, but has shifted to include other games such as chess through mix-ups and misuse ("king me" does not end the game in checkers; rather promotes the piece, as opposed to "checkmate" in checkers *[Source:  [Reddit]](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/2o3ctm/why_is_it_called_checkmate_in_chess_and_king_me/)*)

> **12.** *verb* To promote a piece of draughts/checkers that has traversed the board to the opposite side, that piece subsequently being permitted to move backwards as well as forwards.
>
> > *I was about to make a move that would corner a piece that she was trying to get kinged, but I slid my checker back.*

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/king).

Answer (score 0):

Well "King" in this sense is a verb that means to make superior akin to the ruler of a monarchy or independent state and "me" is a pronoun used by a speaker to refer to himself or herself as the object of a verb or preposition.

king me = means to bestow king like qualities on to someone, however, in the common context it generally means to elevate the rank of a checker piece.

"King Me" = Reference to the game of checkers where a player moves a piece to the last row on the enemies side of the board and gets to elevate the rank of his piece by stacking another piece on top of it.

King me = A command, given by one checkers player to another, to place a single checker on top of another checker that has reached the last row on the enemies side of the board.

King = Elevate to the social rank of King

Me = used by the speaker to refer to himself as the object of a verb or preposition.

The interesting thing about that statement though is not only is it a two word statement that adheres to the subject - verb - object syntax but it does it in reverse... object - verb - subject. And! the king in this sense is both the verb and subject...

This is my thought process so I deleted nothing.